# AngularJS redirect flashes previous template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

This question has been asked a couple of times with no correct answer so hopefully this question/answer will resolve many peoples' issues.

Basically I have a resolve object attached to my routes, like so:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/',
  {
      templateUrl: "html/landing.html",
      controller: "LandingController",
      resolve: {
          app: function ($q, $location) {
              var defer = $q.defer();
              var next = "landing";
              checkRedirect(defer, $location, next);
              return defer.promise;
          }
      }
  });
```

The `checkRedirect` function does a couple of `AJAX` calls and may change the `$location` like so:

```
$location.path("/home");
```

Everything works as expected but for some reason when a redirect occurs, the template from the old route flickers for a split second before redirecting and rendering the correct template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hack that basically hides the body for the "split second" during which the old template flashes. If someone has an actual solution, however, please share.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
    $('body').hide();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('body').show();
    }, 100);
});
```